# API for sending closed captions to a Microsoft Teams meeting

Tags: api, microsoft-teams, cart, closed-captions

Since August 25, 2021, Microsoft Teams has support for CART captioners to send text (captions) to the meeting. This is great!

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/teams-admin

On this page
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-live-captions-in-a-teams-meeting-4be2d304-f675-4b57-8347-cbd000a21260 is described how to obtain the **CART caption link**, to which my software need to connect.

But this is where the information ends. I cannot find the (Graph?) (REST?) API how to make this work.
I have searched the API reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/msteams-client?view=msteams-client-js-latest as well as SDK sources on GitHub. Nothing about CART or captions!

I hope someone can point to me to the documentation on how to feed Closed Captions to a  MS Teams meeting... some Sample code is even better ;-)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have discussed with engineering team and get to know that GET API development is in-progress. There will never be a POST API for it.
We do not have exact ETA to share for now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a CART API endpoint that you can use to push captions to Teams. This is the same URL that you get when you enable CART in the meeting options for your meeting . The [details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/api-references?tabs=dotnet#cart-url) are available on the Teams Meeting Apps API reference page.

Comment: @Sander - Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30928156)